# shibboleth-identityprovider still using javax

Tags: spring-boot, shibboleth, jakarta-migration

We are using Shibboleth identity provider for SSO solution since long time. Now we are planning to migrate our spring application to latest version. Latest versions of Springboot using Tomcat10( Jakarta EE).

But Shibboleth last released on May 18 2020. No latest version available for Shibboleth. When we are doing migration getting compatibility issues Jakarta(Spring latest version) and Javax (Shibboleth).

How to get rid of javax from shibboleth and replace with jakarta?

Answer (score 0):

The Shibboleth Identity Provider v5.0.0 was released 2023-09-13. It is based on Spring Framework 6.0 and the `jakarta` namespaces.

Details can be found here:

https://shibboleth.atlassian.net/wiki/spaces/IDP5/pages/3199500367/ReleaseNotes